# Updating JSON column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I've got a JSON column in Postgres, that contains data in the following structure

```
{
    "listings": [{
            "id": "KTyneMdrAhAEKyC9Aylf",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id": "ZcjK9M4tuwhWWdK8WcfX",
            "active": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to do a few things, all of which I am unsure how to do

1. Add a new object to the listings array
2. Remove an object from the listings array based on its id
3. Update an object in the listings array based on its id

I am also using Sequelize if there are any built in functions to do this (I can't see anything obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=10f72addd3adbdaf22a9dc25adbe2619)

Insert (`jsonb_insert()`):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydata = jsonb_insert(mydata, '{listings, 0}', '{"id":"foo", "active":true}');
```

Update (expand array, change value with `jsonb_set()`, reaggregate):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydata = jsonb_set(mydata, '{listings}', s.a)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        jsonb_agg(
            CASE WHEN elems ->> 'id' = 'foo' THEN jsonb_set(elems, '{active}', 'false')
                ELSE elems
            END
        ) as a
    FROM
        mytable,
        jsonb_array_elements(mydata -> 'listings') AS elems
) s;
```

Delete (expand array, filter relevant elements, reaggregate):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydata = jsonb_set(mydata, '{listings}', s.a)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        jsonb_agg(elems) as a
    FROM
        mytable,
        jsonb_array_elements(mydata -> 'listings') AS elems
    WHERE elems ->> 'id' != 'foo'
) s;
```

Updating and deleting can be done in one line like the inserting. But in that case you have to use the array element index instead of a certain value. If you want to change an array element with a value you need to read it first. This is only possible with a prior expanding.

Comment: Hi, just testing it out now.  It seems to be failing on the Insert one at the moment with `function jsonb_insert(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: If your data is type `json` then you need to cast it into type `jsonb` before and back afterwards. This fiddle uses the casts: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=31e5a2908afb7d891d4c60f2046cb12b

Comment: The only issue I currently have is with the deleting.  I understand what its doing, however if there are no results returned from the select, then it sets the entire field to null, rather than just emptying the listings array

Comment: The you need to catch this case. For example with a CASE clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=be62b9c1df4bb2c2da8124daa06135d7

Comment: Still struggling to get the update delete correct.  I've got multiple columns and its replicating all the data across them, and i also need to compare against the ID column too https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e1ab0acc2cc9b4a9d445ceaae4fda8fd

Comment: if your use case is that complicated, you really should think about a normalized table model and storing the data in separate columns instead of a json object. That's what relational DBMS are made for ;)

Comment: Im confused.  The whole point of a database table is that it supports multiple columns.  I only want to update the items column JSON using the above query, where the column ID matches a value

Comment: You're right: A table contains columns. And you should work with these columns (fitlering, sorting, indexing) instead storing different data in one single column. To update JSON objects as they are, mostly leads into expanding them and simulate columns to be able to filter (example `elems ->> 'foo'`) before any operation. So usually it is better to store these data in different columns to keep the advantages of a DBMS.

Comment: Ah I see, maybe you got confused with my fiddle. In the fiddle I just wanted to demonstrate how you can avoid removing the values on empty subquery results. Nevertheless I did a little bug fix here. Hope to destroy your confusions :) Sry for misunderstandings! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c32398d7fbd2499af8a2df613f77d65a